# Static method not called

Tags: java, static-methods

I'm trying to call a static method (`printABC()`) in this class but it's not working.

If I uncomment both of the lines marked T_T (1 and 2), it works! Why does it fail with only one of the lines?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class pro0009 {
   static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   static int A,B,C;

   static void printABC(){
      String ABC = in.nextLine(); 

      ABC=ABC.replace("A"," "+A+" ");
      ABC=ABC.replace("B"," "+B+" ");
      ABC=ABC.replace("C"," "+C+" ");

      //System.out.print(ABC.substring(1));
      System.out.print(ABC);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      int x = in.nextInt(); //1
      int y = in.nextInt(); //2
      int z = in.nextInt(); //3


      if(x<y){//1<2
         if(x<z){ //1<3
            if(y<z){//x<y<z 2<3
               //1<2<3
               A=x;
               B=y;
               C=z;
               printABC();//T_T 1
               System.out.println("Here");
               //pro0009.printABC();//T_T 2
               //System.out.println("Here2");
            }else{ //x<z<y
               A=x;
               B=z;
               C=y;

            }
         }else{//z<x<y
            A=z;
            B=x;
            C=y;

         }
      }else{//y<x
         if(y<z){
            if(x<z){//y<x<z
               A=y;
               B=x;
               C=z;

            }else{//y<z<x
               A=y;
               B=z;
               C=x;

            }
         }else{//z<y<x
            A=z;
            B=y;
            C=x;

         }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: When I see such a formulated question, something wants to cry deep inside of me:(

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What do you expect it to do, and what does it actually do? There seems to be a lot of code there that is not relevant. Can you reduce it to just the important parts?

Comment: @Smile: *how* does it fail? You're not providing us with any useful information here! What output are you expecting, what are you getting instead, what are your inputs...

Comment: thank! i try to input 1 2 3 but printABC() not called in my screen cursor skip to "Here"

Comment: `printABC` calls `in.nextLine` - what input do you give it? The first `1 2 3` will be assigned to `A`, `B` and `C`, but what do you enter later?

Comment: ah.. still not work :S why it not waiting for input T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T_T 1 consumes the line entered. There's nothing for the in.nextLine() to consume in the buffer at T_T 2, so it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

since you are calling a static method within a another static method, this should not cause a problem. The problem should be with the logic of the program. Please provide more details regarding teh functionality you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The three `nextInt`s in the beginning of the program don't eat the line terminator. First time `nextLine` is called, it reads the input upto this terminator and returns empty string. So the first `printABC` prints empty string as well. When `nextLine` is called for the second time, it reads the next line in the input which is what you expect.

To fix this you can simply call `nextLine` twice in `printABC`, ignoring the result of the first call, since it should always be empty.